# How to parse string into BigDecimal uniformly?

Tags: java, parsing, bigdecimal

I am gettings strings as the input for a program, but those could be represented in various formats. E.g.:

- 8900
- 8.9E+3
- 89E+2
- 8900.000

All those numbers are equal *mathematically* and the following program also tells a match:

```
public class BigDecimalMain {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("8900");
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("8.9E+3");
        BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("89E+2");
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("8900.000");

        System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(c));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(d));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
```

My program uses *.equals* to match objects and it fails to give the right answer in the case above.

**Question:** How to parse string into BigDecimal uniformly? I mean the following:

```
find a function PARSE, that    
for any STR1 && STR2
PARSE(STR1).compareTo(PARSE(STR2)) == 0 <=> PARSE(STR1).equals(PARSE(STR2))
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the input number will be an integer value (whatever its format)?

Comment: Use setScale(xxx) on every created BigDecimal. However this makes only sense if there is a useful common xxx that can be used for every value in your code. See sample in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With a common scale you could use setScale(xxx):

```
    {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("8900");
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("8.9E+3");
        BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("89E+2");
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("8900.000");

        System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(c));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(d));
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(a.equals(c));
        System.out.println(a.equals(d));
    }
    {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("8900").setScale(5);
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("8.9E+3").setScale(5);
        BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("89E+2").setScale(5);
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("8900.000").setScale(5);

        System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(c));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(d));
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(a.equals(c));
        System.out.println(a.equals(d));
    }
```

shows

```
0
0
0
false
false
false
0
0
0
true
true
true
```

Comment: Please, take a look at my finding. It shows similar approach, but not bound to the source data and somewhat more generic.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following approach:

```
class UniformDecimal {

    private final BigDecimal decimal;

    public UniformDecimal(BigDecimal decimal) {
        this.decimal = decimal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return decimal.toBigInteger().mod(BigInteger.valueOf((1<<31)-1)).intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UniformDecimal that = (UniformDecimal) o;
        return that.decimal.compareTo(this.decimal)==0;
    }
}
```

Though, I'm not sure about hashCode implementation

Comment: That'll work for sure, but imagine reworking huge codebase + 3rd-party systems. It doesn't seem realistic after all.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE.** It seems that [stripTrailingZeros()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros()) does the thing!

Found something useful at here: [HiveDecimal](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/common/type/HiveDecimal.java)

```
 private static BigDecimal normalize(BigDecimal bd, boolean allowRounding) {
        if (bd == null) {
            return null;
        }

        bd = trim(bd);

        int intDigits = bd.precision() - bd.scale();

        if (intDigits > MAX_PRECISION) {
            return null;
        }

        int maxScale = Math.min(MAX_SCALE, Math.min(MAX_PRECISION - intDigits, bd.scale()));
        if (bd.scale() > maxScale) {
            if (allowRounding) {
                bd = bd.setScale(maxScale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                // Trimming is again necessary, because rounding may introduce new trailing 0's.
                bd = trim(bd);
            } else {
                bd = null;
            }
        }

        return bd;
    }

    private static BigDecimal trim(BigDecimal d) {
        if (d.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            // Special case for 0, because java doesn't strip zeros correctly on that number.
            d = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        } else {
            d = d.stripTrailingZeros();
            if (d.scale() < 0) {
                // no negative scale decimals
                d = d.setScale(0);
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
```